# Adding voice control with Google Assistant

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

For two days I am researching the Google Assistant, but after these two days I am confused. It seems like the previous tutorials where more about creating an app for the Google Assistant, but I would like to do the opposite.

I already have a running app, and I would like to add the possibility to navigate through the app with voice commands that are handled by the Google Assistant.

I got lost in my searches. Does anyone have a starting point for me to achieve my goal? Which points could be useful for me?

Comment: Thankyou. I just the same intent as you and this pointed in the right vector. Well, the NickFelker answer  actually is a 2 choices, but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to integrate voice commands only within the context of your application, it may be a good idea to use [Dialogflow](http://docs.dialogflow.com/). It will use Google Cloud's speech to text while giving you the ability to handle your intents. There's [a sample](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client) which uses Android.

Using the Google Assistant would also be possible with the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/). There is [a sample](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant) which uses Android Things, but is easily portable to any Android device. It would let you send voice commands to the Assistant and get back responses. However, it is slightly more general. If a user asks about something in your app, they will probably only want an answer within the context of your app, not fallback to the Assistant.